# How can I remove all non-English tokens from sklearn TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

`TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=ngram_range, min_df=0, stop_words=lang)`

I am trying to vectorize my corpus but my corpus contains both English & Arabic words. I want to remove arabic words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use strip_accents = "ascii" :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
     'This is the first document. সহজ  نعم فعلا' ,
     'This document is the second document. সহজ نعم فعلا',
     'And this is the third one.',
     'Is this the first document?',
 ]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents = "ascii")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

output:

```
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```

Comment: This works like magic but would you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: strip_accents = "ascii" is a fast method that only works on characters that have an direct ASCII mapping. Other languages except english have not directly mapped. So it only consider english here.

Comment: you can check sklearn doc : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using regex by passing the `token_pattern` parameter:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern = '[a-z]+\w*')
```

PS: The following regex looks for any word with the letters `a-z` specifically and returns. them.

Output:

```
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```